# How can i sync blockhain of two localnodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, lighthouse

i'm new to ethereum. I ran two local nodes from the same genesis. One node has a blockchain filled with data, the other is just empty, I wanted to synchronize them for learning purposes. After I added the peer of the filled node to the empty node, I started getting a message "Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!".

After installing lighthouse I realized that I could use mainnet, testnet and a few others, but not my local --networkid 3. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: you probably messed up with chain ids or parameters. You are running a node with PoS (Proof of Stake) consensus. This configuration requires Beacon client which you don't have. You need to switch back to Proof of Work (or Proof of Authority consensus)

Comment: ohh , of course you did. Chain id = 3 is Ropsten, it is a testnet. You have to pick some number that is not used, like above 1000 or so